# Time mismatch in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

When I get the date object and print it in mongo shell, it display two different time as follows:

>new Date()
Mon Feb 06 2012 18:49:40 GMT+0530 (IST)
>printjson({created_at: new Date()})
{ created_at : ISODate("2012-02-06T13:19:40.313Z") }

The two times are different, what i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of mongodb always store dates in UTC format, but javascript show your local time. And printjson internal mongodb shell function that convert date from your local timezone to utc format. So it shows -5.30 hours backward from your current time.

Comment: I want the first time to be printed in json format, any suggestion. because I used the same date object in condition statement, it give me wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

The times are not different, they are exactly the same! It's merely the same time expressed in different timezones. The "Z" in ISODate means "UTC" (or as some people try to call it: GMT). You're on IST (Indian Standard Time I guess) which is at GMT+0530. 18:49:40 @ GMT+5:30 is exactly the same as 13:19 @ GMT.

When I run the same code you shown on the shell, I get:

```
> new Date()
ISODate("2012-02-06T13:34:10.667Z")
```

As you can see, that is also with "Z". Perhaps you're running an older version of the shell?

cheers,
Derick