# Mongodb faulty date

Tags: mongodb

I'm using version 2.4.8 of mongo but i've also tested the following with older versions.

Typing `new Date(2014,0,14)` in the mongo console returns `ISODate("2014-01-13T18:30:00Z")`
 which seems to be off by a day. Is this expected behavior(ISODate stores this way) or an anomaly?

Comment: Probably caused by your timezone - check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160744/time-mismatch-in-mongo-shell which looks like a duplicate of your question.

Comment: Thanks, that answered it. The question didn't come up when I searched though.